# Why doesn't my CPU downclock when idling?

Tags: cpufreq, frequency

i've been fixing the Overheating, thanks for that, it worked, i just reopened my laptop and cleaned it VERY well.
but now idle is @ 50*C and not 20-30*C, because of the frequency being at max 2.5GHz.
but normaly, at idle, the freq should be very low, like @ 1.2
but when i change it on the freq scaling on Unity, it get back to 2.5..
Any help?

Ubuntu 11.10, i5 M460 @ 2.5GHz

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "but when i change it on the freq scaling on Unity, it get back to 2.5"?

Have you tried`echo "ondemand" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`? This would normally save your last used power mode too. Other available power-mode-options are available with `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors`.

Comment: yes, i did tryed them, well, with that, i mean, when i'm on userspace governor, i can't control the CPU freq, like, when i select 1.6GHz, it goes back to 2.5GHz is seconds...
and even ondemand, it use 2.5GHz.

Comment: do you experience this behaviour on another system as well? You might want to check that to determine if it is a software or a hardware problem.

Comment: Well, on windows i never had this.

Comment: is the PC really idling? Use top to check that there isn't a process taking useless CPU power (because it is stuck in a loop or similar)

Comment: i've checked everything, but today, i had an update, updated my pc, rebooted and i got control of my frequency back, agin thanks guys